# Why can't I use the power rule on this partial derivative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, complex-numbers, partial-derivative

I came across this question on Khan Academy:

let $f(x, y, z) = \sqrt{xyz}$, find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg\rvert_{(-1, -1, 4)}$

My first intuition was to use the power rule:

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\sqrt{yz}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\big(\sqrt{x}\big)=\frac{\sqrt{yz}}{2\sqrt{x}}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg\rvert_{(-1, -1, 4)}=\frac{\sqrt{yz}}{2\sqrt{x}}\bigg\rvert_{(-1, -1, 4)}=\frac{\sqrt{(-1)(4)}}{2\sqrt{-1}}=\frac{i\sqrt{4}}{2i}=\frac{2i}{2i}=1
$$

However, the official solution used the chain rule and arrived at a different result
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial (xyz)}\cdot\frac{\partial (xyz)}{\partial x}=\frac{yz}{2\sqrt{xyz}}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg\rvert_{(-1, -1, 4)}=\frac{yz}{2\sqrt{xyz}}\bigg\rvert_{(-1, -1, 4)}=\frac{(-1)(4)}{2\sqrt{(-1)(-1)(4)}}=\frac{-4}{2\sqrt{4}}=\frac{-4}{4}=-1
$$
Where was my mistake? If it was with the differentiation, what are some situations where I'm not allowed to take the power rule? If it was with complex numbers, what would be a general rule to prevent myself from making this mistake again? (I know $\sqrt{(-1)(-1)} \neq\sqrt{-1}\cdot\sqrt{-1}$ but that's about it)

Comment: Your error is not in applying the power rule, or the taking out of the constants. Your error is precisely related to what you know in parenthesis that you said you know. When you did $\sqrt{xyz}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{yz}$

Comment: If you want to do it your way with splitting the square root up into factors, you would need to write $\sqrt{xyz} = \sqrt{-yz}\sqrt{-x}$ instead (whether the resulting application of the chain rule is any better than the official solution is purely a matter of opinion).

Comment: When working with complex numbers, always remember that $a^ba^c=a^{b+c}$ and $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ are no longer true. When in doubt, reach out to the definition $a^b=e^{b\ln(a)}$, and perhaps a specific branch of $\ln(a)$ chosen in the problem in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error has already been mentioned in a comment, but here are further details:

You are supposed to evaluate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$
at a point where $x < 0$ and $yz < 0$.
Therefore $\sqrt{xyz}$ is the square root of a positive number,
but $\sqrt{yz}$ and $\sqrt{x}$ are square roots of negative numbers,
and therefore $\sqrt{yz} \sqrt{x} \neq \sqrt{xyz}$;
it is exactly the same thing as $\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1} \neq \sqrt{1}$,
just with some positive factors inserted in all the square roots.